What model or method to use for categorical data with repeated measures?
I am trying to analyze my data, it consists of 2 independent categorical variables (4 textures and 4 impact sounds - mixing and matching them gives me 16 different conditions that each person is shown) and 1 dependent categorical variable (the option selected for the stimulus shown- 4 potential options). I plotted my graphs and have an idea of the results but need to prove its statistical significance.
I'm not entirely certain how to do this so I was considering multinomial logistic regression - I could use the model to verify that the results we are seeing are not random but an actual pattern. My understanding is that we can validate this based on the p-value of the model. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.
But my data also has repeated measures... How do I account for that? Does the Multinomial logistic regression already consider that? Or should I look towards Mixed effects Logistic regression? Does python support that? I can't seem to find any support for it or code examples.
I was considering splitting my multinomial data into 4 different binomial mixed regression models, but once again I can't seem to find anything on Mixed effects logistic regression - only Mixed effects linear regression in python. Can I achieve the correct results using the linear mixed effects model?

A single model is generally preferred. If the outcome is ordered, then you could employ what is called an ordinal model, but if not ordered, then multinomial logit is the way to go. See Pymer4 for fitting such models in Python https://eshinjolly.com/pymer4/
